# Select A Rendering Not Recognizing Allowed Controls From Placeholder after App Pool Recycle

Tags: solr, experience-editor, presentation, lucene

I'm experiencing an issue in Sitecore 9.0.2, Lucene index, and 10.2, Solr index, where some, but not all, of our placeholders in Experience Editor are not recognizing the renderings inside the Allowed Controls and produce the below version of Select a Rendering rather than the listing of all allowed renderings.

[image: Select a Rendering]

Typically I'll uncheck the "editable" box, save it, recheck, save it again, and then our list of renderings appears in the Add Component Select a Rendering window. Resaving the item only works until the next app pool recycle though at which point we'll receive the above Select a Rendering window.

Currently we use Unicorn to handle syncing and tracking of our placeholder items, however, I've removed them from Unicorn's watch list and still have the same issue after an app pool recycle.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I'm running out of ideas. At first I thought it was a Lucene issue. Unfortunately, our current upgrade has proved otherwise as a fresh install of 10.2 (with our code applied) using Solr is producing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

We went ahead and created a new Placeholder item with the same placeholder key and the issue no longer exists.